# What is the distribution function of $x$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a question asked in previous years' question paper that I am studying for

the question states:

A random variable has an exponential probability function given by $f(x)=ae^{-b|x|​}$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Find the relationship between a and b and also the distribution function of $x$.

Comment: Need clarification: support of the pdf, any known probabilities, etc.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: A relationship between $a$ and $b$ is the equality $\int f(x)dx=1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, I am actually new.

Comment: @drhab  the limits will be from a to b? or negative infinity to infinity. I am new at this, I am from humanities background.

Comment: @exalibusias, an exponential probability function is only defined from infinity to $0$

Comment: @HarryAlli looks like it could be defined on all of $\Bbb R$ given that absolute value sign

Comment: @snulty if we define it in $\Bbb R$ the answer changes. I have two answers that way.

Comment: @exalibusias well the absolute value is a bit redundant if you don't plan on using positive and negative numbers $\ldots$

Comment: @exalibusias If you wern't new, I wouldn't have welcome you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1: Consider only positive values of $x$
$$\int^\infty_0 ae^{-bx}dx=1$$
$$\lim_{y\to \infty }[-\frac{a}{b}e^{-bx}]^y_0=1$$
$$\lim_{y\to \infty}-\frac{a}{b}e^{-by}+\frac{a}{b}=1$$
$$\frac{a}{b}=1$$

Case 2 as suggested by snulty, consider all real values of $x$.

$$\int^\infty_0 ae^{-bx}dx+\int^0_{-\infty}ae^{bx}dx=1$$ I ignore the modulus, and split the function up.

$$\lim_{y\to \infty,z\to -\infty}[-\frac{a}{b}e^{-bx}]^y_0+[\frac{a}{b}e^{bx}]^0_z=1$$
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{b}=1$$
$$2a=b$$

Comment: Spot on, matched with my solution.I just read up some material trying to understand the exponential distribution. I found out since it is using a modulus sign, it is called a double exponential distribution, which has its standard form where: ${2a=b}$ so may be a tip for next time.